# Capture the putty log to a file

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

I start putty from a linux terminal.When it starts/invoked i set the serial line and the speed option. I want to capture what ever that is shown on the putty to a file after doing the above.How to do this by using a command during invoking the putty from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but check the "script" command in linux.  It *might* do the job - works fine with native ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Putty has a -log option, that works for me.

```
putty -log logfile
```